# python keras neural network prediction not working (outputs 0 or 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have created with keras a neural network for predicting addition.
I have 2 inputs and 1 output (result of adding the 2 inputs).

I trained my neural network with tensorflow and then I tried to predict addition but the program returns `0` or `1` value not `3,4,5,etc`.

This is my code :

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
# load dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("data.csv", delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:2]
Y = dataset[:,2]
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=2, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10,  verbose=2)



# calculate predictions
predictions = model.predict(X)
# round predictions
rounded = [round(x[0]) for x in predictions]
print(rounded)
```

And my file `data.csv`:

```
1,2,3
3,3,6
4,5,9
10,8,18
1,3,4
5,3,8
```

For example:

```
1+2=3
3+3=6
4+5=9
...etc.
```

But I get this as output : `0,1,0,0,1,0,1...`
Why didn't I get the output as `3,6,9...`?

i updated code for use other loss function but i have same error :

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
# load pima indians dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("data.csv", delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:2]
Y = dataset[:,2]
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=2, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=2, init='uniform', activation='linear'))

# Compile model
#model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10,  verbose=2)



# calculate predictions
predictions = model.predict(X)
# round predictions
rounded = [round(x[0]) for x in predictions]
print(rounded)
```

outout=1,1,1,3,1,1,...etc

Comment: Why did you comment the `Dense(12)` and `Dense(2)` layers?

Comment: It was just to test. I forgot to uncomment them.

Comment: Try `Dense(8)` instead of `Dense(2)` or other architectures (see edited answer).

Answer (score 3):

As @ebeneditos mentioned, you need to change your activation function in the last layer to something other than sigmoid. You can try changing it to linear.

```
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='linear'))
```

You should also change your loss function to something like mean squared error, as your problem is more of a regression problem than a classification problem (binary_crossentropy is used as a loss function for binary classification problems)

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i updated my code with your loss function, but i have same probleme, outout=1,1,1,3,1,1,...etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the [Sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) you have in the last layer. As it is defined:

[image: sigmoid]

It can only take values from 0 to 1. You should change last layer's activation function.

You can try this instead (with `Dense(8)` instead of `Dense(2)`):

```
# Create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=2, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='linear'))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10,  verbose=2)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i tried to change these values and i just tried your solution but i still have the same problem

Comment: You can take ideas from here maybe: https://www.quora.com/Can-a-neural-network-learn-addition